# Visual Studio Code: When I try to "Open New Command Prompt" nothing happens

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've tried the key combination (Ctrl-Shift-C), as well as clicking the item in the command palette, but neither results in anything happening on my machine.  No error, no command prompt, nothing.  Everything else seems to be working in VS Code, so not sure why this isn't, but would really appreciate any help.  Is there a log somewhere that might indicate what happens when I attempt to open a command prompt?

FYI, I'm running v 0.10.6, in Windows 7 Pro 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Hi Eddie did you already tried to open it using `F1`? I am in version 0.10.5 and maybe it's a bug in your version. You could try reporting that to vscode issues on github. But according to the VS Code Key Bindings list the shortcup you are trying isn't available. You can, of course, create yours typing `F1` then searching for `key`. Then you can create something like this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+p",
    "command": "workbench.action.showCommands",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings